# How to print a string that has integers inside of it C++

Tags: c++

I am appending an integer to a String reference called output inside a function. I made a String called output in another function and I passed it by reference an argument to the function. However when I try to print it I get a bunch of weird symbols ��������������������. I tried to use sstream for output but it didn't work:

Student.cc

```
void Student::makeString(string& output){
    output += fname + "\t"; // this is a string
    output += lname + "\t"; // this is a string
    output += id + "\t"; // this is an int   
}
```

IO.cc

```
void IO::printInfo(Student& student){
    string output = "";
    student.makeString(output);

    // doesnt work
    cout << output << endl;

    // doesn't work
    stringstream ss;
    ss << output;
    cout << ss.str() << endl;
}
```

I still get creepy characters. Help!

Comment: You need to convert numbers to string before merging. `output += std::to_string(id) + "\t";`.

Comment: `output += id + "\t";` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: `id + "\t"` looks like the addition of an integer and (what decays to) a pointer, and thus results in (undefined behavior which probably manifests as) a pointer to random memory occurring some number of characters after where the string literal is stored in memory. You probably don't mean to try and append the string starting at that memory location to `output`.

Comment: In addition to @Hurkyl's excellent suggestion, make `makeString` a function which returns the string rather than taking it by variable reference.  So it becomes: `std::string Student::makeString() const {
    std::ostringstream ostr;  ostr << fname << '\t' << lname << '\t' << id << '\t';  return ostr.str() }`.  I've also made `makeString` a const member function.

Answer (score 1):

```
output += id + "\t"; // this is an int
```

is equivalent to

```
output += (id + "\t");
```

which is equivalent to:

```
char const* s1 = "\t";
char const* s2 = s1 + id;
output += s2;
```

Unless `id` is `1` or `0`, that leads to accessing memory that you are not supposed to, which causes undefined behavior.

I am guessing you want to append the string representation of `id` plus `"\t"` to `output`. you can use:

```
output += std::to_string(id);
output += "\t";
```